# End of the spotlight

Tags: light

I have some issues with the spotlight (Im using blender 2.8). Actually, I have a spotlight in top of a box. I want my spotlight to go throught the box (see inside) but I want to end it after the box. In other words, i want the light to stop emitting after the box edge. I tried to cast shadow on different elements but no success.

*note: I need to have the spotlight above the box to have the perfect cone.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear: can you share some screenshots and/or a .blend file to show us your situation and your intentions?

If you want shadows, but you don't have them, we need to look at your setup, if you have them, but you don't want them, we need to know, for example, what render engine are you using...

Comment: I just added a picture hehe! It is not the real work because it is confidential but here the simulation

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but the question is still very unclear... You don't have to share your project, but at least give us more informations. For now I'll try to interpret your question as best as I can, and I'll edit it later if you explain yourself better.

The way I understood it is that you want your light to shine through the top face of your object, but not through the bottom faces. I assume you want your top face to be a solid material, and I assume you want to keep it all as one single object. I'll also assume the spotlight direction is always above the object and that you don't want to have extra objects (e.g. shadow catchers). As you can see a lot of assumptions here.

In this case you can do it with 2 different materials applied to the cube. On the bottom faces you have your normal material, while on the top face you have this material:

[image]

The principled shader is your material, the other nodes are just there to allow the light to go through the face itself